# Value based conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have 2 cells a1 and  a2, which may have negative or postive values. I want the color of both the cells to change to green if value in either cell is between -10 to 10. And red if the value in either cell is between 10 to 20 or -10 to -20 and purple if the value in either cell exceeds 20 or -20. Can any one help me with the query.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

It's not about a query, it's about **conditional formatting**.

choose the cell and select "conditional formatting" from the menu.

[image]

Choose "New Rule" and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

**Example** -

A rule to color all cells higher than `-10` and lower then `10` as red background:

[image]

Create several rules on the same selected cell to format it according to your wishes.

Comment: If a1 is 5 and a2 is 15 i want both a1 and a2 cells to reflect as red.

Comment: You can still do that with conditional formatting. Click the "Formula" button and format your formula @Kartik.

Comment: Struggling to apply the formula that is why i posted it here. :)

Comment: In the format fomula bar, you can write, for example: `="A1 >-10 AND A2 < 10"`

Answer (score 0):

Koby Douek gave a great instructional answer to this question.  I will add step-by-step instructions for you.

1. Click on "Conditional Formatting" in the "Home" tab.  Click on "Manage Rules..." (Alternatively, type Alt+H, Alt+L, Alt+R)
2. Click "New Rule..."
3. Select the last option: "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. In the formula bar, type `=AND($A$1<10,$A$1>-10)`
5. Click "Format", change Fill color to Red.
6. Click OK.  You will now see the screen you were on before.  Change the "Applies to" column to `=$A$1:$A$2`.
7. Click "New Rule..." again
8. Select the last option: "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
9. In the formula bar, type `=AND($A$2<10,$A$2>-10)`
10. Click "Format", change Fill color to Red.
11. Click OK.  You will now see the screen you were on before.  Change the "Applies to" column to `=$A$1:$A$2`.  You should see this screen now: [image]
12. Continue this process... Add `=AND($A$1<20,$A$1>10)` with red format, `=AND($A$2<20,$A$2>10)` with red format, `=AND($A$1<-10,$A$1>-20)` with purple format, `=AND($A$2<-10,$A$2>-20)` with purple format
13. Now you should see this screen:[image]

Finally, this is what you are looking for.  You can change the priority of the conditional formatting using the up and down arrows in the top part of the "Manage Rules" popup window (meaning you can make green take precedence over red, if you would like).

There you are, an overview of conditional formatting!  Happy formatting.  Also, next time, please try this yourself before asking us for help, and show us your progress so we do not need to go step-by-step if you don't need it.